# Why is a Java String hash code lazy generated?

Tags: java, string, lazy-initialization

It appears in java.lang.String.java, that Java will only generate the hashcode, and then store it, after a call to hashcode(), but why not just make the hashcode in the constructor?

The relevant code:

```
if (h == 0 && count > 0) {
    int off = offset;
    char val[] = value;
    int len = count;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        h = 31*h + val[off++];
    }

    hash = h;
}
```

could for the most part be placed in the constructor.

Comment: If you find an acceptable answer you can tick it to let people know you have an answer to your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why spend time generating a hash code that most likely will not be used? Most strings are constructed, used and then garbage collected without the hashcode() ever being called.

Comment: Many strings will get equality-checked in their lifetime.  Checking two unequal strings for equality if their hash codes have been computed is generally very fast.  Further, for some hashcode implementations, including the one in Java, it is possible to compute the hashcode for the concatenation of two strings in constant time (actually time O(lgN), but that quantity is bounded and the constant term can be fairly small).

Answer (score 5):

Joshua Bloch call this practice 'racy single-check'.

Jeremy Manson has excellent explanation of why it's done and why it'safe: [on his blog](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com.au/2008/12/benign-data-races-in-java.html)

In essence, at construction time you save some time by skipping calculating hash code. In multithreaded environment you'll pay for this back because multiple thread potentially could do the same calculation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the correct forum for this and the question will likely be closed. You can try asking in programmers.stackexchange.com.

One reason could be that computing hashCode is not cheap and it is required only in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

2 reasons:

1) Computing `hashCode()` is not cheap: is an `O(n)` complexity on the string's length, so better do it only when need it.

and:

2) String instances are immutable: Since they never change, you always compute `hashCode()` at most one time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit when placing it in the constructor. But there's a downside when it would be in the constructor. When hashCode for a String is never called then computation was done for nothing. And when you call hashCode() then it is calculated once in both cases - just in different places and time.